# What is the test of for randomness

Tags: random

How do you tell if a large sequential sample taken from a 0-1 rectangular parent - and presented as random - is truly random?

Comment: Big and important subject! You will find basic information, and some references, [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests)

Comment: thanks Andre. And for the one earlier today also.  bucky